# Java error: The method add(String) is undefined for the type String

Tags: java

Whenever I try to run my code, I get the error "The method add(String) is undefined for the type String," "The method subtract(String) is undefined for the type String," and so on for the multiply and divide methods. I don't know if the rest of my code runs correctly because I haven't been able to run the actual program. Why am I getting this error?

**Main:**

```
import java.util.*;

public class RationalNumberMain 
{

      public static void main(String[] args) 
      {

          Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

          System.out.print("Enter first fraction here: ");
          String r1 = s.nextLine();

          System.out.print("Enter second fraction here: ");
          String r2 = s.nextLine();

          RationalNumber x = new RationalNumber(r1);
          RationalNumber y = new RationalNumber(r2);

            System.out.println("Rational Number 1 is " + r1);
            System.out.println("Rational number 2 is " + r2);
            System.out.println(r1 + " + " + r2 + " = " + r1.add(r2));
            System.out.println(r1 + " - " + r2 + " = " + r1.subtract(r2));
            System.out.println(r1 + " * " + r2 + " = " + r1.multiply(r2));
            System.out.println(r1 + " / " + r2 + " = " + r1.divide(r2));
      }
}
```

**Class:**

```
public class RationalNumber 
{

    private String fraction;
    private String s1;
    private String s2;
    private int num;
    private int den;
    private int combineNum;
    private int combineDen;
    private String finalFraction;
    private int divideNum;
    private int divideDen;


    public RationalNumber(String userFraction) 
    {
        fraction = userFraction;
        s1 = "";
        s1 = "";
        num = 0;
        den = 0;
        combineNum = 0;
        combineDen = 0;
        finalFraction = "";
        divideNum = 0;
        divideDen = 0;
    }

    public String toString() 
    {
        return fraction;
    }

    public void seperate()
    {
        s1 = fraction.substring(0,1);
        s2 = fraction.substring(2);
        num = Integer.parseInt(s1);
        den = Integer.parseInt(s2);

    }

    public int getNum() 
    {
        return num;
    }

    public int getDen() 
    {
        return den;
    }

    public String add(RationalNumber x) 
    {
        combineDen = den * x.getDen();
        combineNum = (num * x.getDen()) + (x.getNum() * den);
        finalFraction = String.valueOf(combineDen) + "/" + String.valueOf(combineNum);
        return finalFraction;
    }

    public String subtract(RationalNumber x) 
    {
        combineDen = den * x.getDen();
        combineNum = (num * x.getDen()) - (x.getNum() * den);
        finalFraction = String.valueOf(combineDen) + "/" + String.valueOf(combineNum);
        return finalFraction;
    }

    public String multiply(RationalNumber x) 
    {
        combineDen = den * x.getDen();
        combineNum = num * x.getNum();
        finalFraction = String.valueOf(combineDen) + "/" + String.valueOf(combineNum);
        return finalFraction;
    }

    public String divide(RationalNumber x) 
    {
        divideNum = x.getDen();
        divideDen = x.getNum();
        combineDen = den * divideDen;
        combineNum = num * divideNum;
        finalFraction = String.valueOf(combineDen) + "/" + String.valueOf(combineNum);
        return finalFraction;
    }

}
```

Comment: Don't you mean `add(x)` and `add(y)` instead of `r1` and `r2`? This is why it's good to *use meaningful variable names*, not arbitrary ones like `x` or `r`. Your method expects a `RationalNumber` and you are passing a `String`.

Comment: Have you a JDK properly installed and configured? Do the code ever ran before?

Answer (score 3):

`r1` is of type `String`:

```
String r1 = s.nextLine();
```

What you want it to add objects of type `RationalNumber` (created from `r1`):

```
RationalNumber x = new RationalNumber(r1);
```

that is:

**`x.add(y)`** instead of `r1.add(r2)`

And the same for other arithmetic operations in your code.

Answer (score 2):

These lines of code should be interacting with the rational numbers, not the input.

```
        System.out.println(r1 + " + " + r2 + " = " + x.add(y));
        System.out.println(r1 + " - " + r2 + " = " + x.subtract(y));
        System.out.println(r1 + " * " + r2 + " = " + x.multiply(y));
        System.out.println(r1 + " / " + r2 + " = " + x.divide(y));
```

An IDE like IntelliJ would have shown that x and y were created but never used.  That would have been a good clue that something was not as you were planning.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you expect. `java.util.String` does not have any of these method `add`, `subtract`, `multiply`, `divide`.

Did you mean:

```java
System.out.println(r1 + " + " + r2 + " = " + x.add(y));
System.out.println(r1 + " - " + r2 + " = " + x.subtract(y));
System.out.println(r1 + " * " + r2 + " = " + x.multiply(y));
System.out.println(r1 + " / " + r2 + " = " + x.divide(y));
```